# How to pass uint16_t* for enum

Tags: c++, enums

```
typedef enum : uint16_t
{
    typeScan     = 11,
    typeSell     = 12,
    typeBuy      = 13
} actionString;

..
..
..

class classB
{
public:
    const char* getStatus(actionString, uint16_t*);
}
```

When implementing

```
classB b = new classB();

const char* statusText = b -> getStatus(typeScan, ...);
```

what do I pass in the second parameter? I am very new to this language and not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Which language is this? It looks like c++ but you have many tags.

Comment: It is a 3rd library in my xcode project (objective-c)

Comment: How would we know? You didn't even tell us what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi It is c++. Please help. I am not sure why so many down votes. Whats wrong?

Comment: BTW, common coding convention is to supply a variable name in your function declarations.  This helps the reader differentiate parameters when the types are the same.

Comment: Reminder, please refrain from using `new` to create instances of variables.  Only use `new` when necessary, such as nodes in a list or when the quantity is unknown during run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the function declaration:

```
const char* getStatus(actionString, uint16_t*);
```

You have two valid choices when passing a pointer:
1) Pass nullptr:

```
  actionString a;
  const char * p_status = getStatus(a, nullptr);
```

2) Pass a pointer to *an existing variable*:

```
actionString a;
uint16_t     value = 0U;
const char * p_status - getStatus(a, &value);
```

Other choices may result in undefined behavior.

Passing `nullptr` may cause undefined behavior if `getStatus` does not adequately handle null pointers.

Please review the sections about pointers in your favorite C++ reference.